# I want Hours,Min, second difference from two datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, datetime

I am developing Time management system for employees.

I want the duration how much duration employee come late , or he went early.

i have following structure.

```
**Attendace**  
AutoId --uniqueidentifier             
EMployeeId --uniqueidentifier
Date   --datetime
InTime -- varchar(50)
OutTime -- varchar(50)
ActualInTime--datetime
ActualOutTime--datetime
```

I want Late Coming Report ( i.e. who came late in morning after ActualInTime and how much duration in hh:mm:ss ) and also want early going(i.e who went early in the evening before ActualOutTime in duration in format hh:mm:ss )

So can you please help me..???

Comment: Have a look at the [DateDiff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) function.

Comment: What is the difference between InTime and ActualInTime. Why is InTime not datetime?

Comment: Just a side point, as you're using SQL Server 2008, you could use the new DATE and TIME datatypes instead of DATETIME/VARCHAR(50). Ideal for this kind of scenario. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724(v=SQL.100).aspx#DateandTimeDataTypes

Comment: Becuase we are storing in full 24 hour format with AM/PM...so kept it varchar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this code might help you...

```
DECLARE @First datetime
DECLARE @Second datetime
SET @First = '04/02/2008 05:23:22'
SET @Second = getdate()

SELECT DATEDIFF(day,@First,@Second)*24 as TotalHours,
DATEDIFF(day,@First,@Second)*24*60 as TotalMinutes,
DATEDIFF(day,@First,@Second)*24*60*60 as TotalSeconds
```

Comment: SELECT DATEDIFF(hour,'2020-06-10 07:16:11.823',GETUTCDATE()) as TotalHours
SELECT DATEDIFF(minute,'2020-06-10 07:16:11.823',GETUTCDATE()) as TotalMinutes

Answer (score 27):

I came across an easier way of solving this issue.

First, a quick example of turning a "number of seconds" into the "hh:mm:ss" format.

```
DECLARE @NumberOfSeconds int
SET @NumberOfSeconds = 3843     --  1 hour, 4 minutes, 3 seconds

SELECT @NumberOfSeconds AS 'seconds',
   CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(second, @NumberOfSeconds, 0), 108) AS 'hh:mm:ss'
```

This will give us this output:

[image]

And we can easily take this a step further, calculate the number of seconds between two datetimes, and display it in `hh:mm:ss` format:

```
DECLARE 
    @NumberOfSeconds int,
    @StartTime datetime = '2017-09-14 14:16:11',
    @EndTime datetime = '2017-09-14 14:23:13'

SET @NumberOfSeconds = DATEDIFF(second, @StartTime, @EndTime)

SELECT @NumberOfSeconds AS 'seconds',
     CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(second, @NumberOfSeconds, 0), 108) AS 'hh:mm:ss'
```

Which gives us this output:

[image]

Simple, hey ?

(And yes, you can simplify it further by putting the `DATEDIFF` directly into the `DATEADD` function.)

Answer (score 23):

You can do it in a very simple way:

```
declare  @date1 datetime, @date2 datetime
set @date1=DATEADD(s,-638,getdate())
set @date2=GETDATE()

select convert(char(8),dateadd(s,datediff(s,@date1,@date2),'1900-1-1'),8)
```

... the result is **00:10:38** (638s = 600s + 38s = 10 minutes and 38 seconds)

Another example:

```
select distinct convert(char(8),dateadd(s,datediff(s, CRDATE , GETDATE() ),'1900-1-1'),8) from sysobjects order by 1
```

It will works until the difference of 86399 seconds (23:59:59):

```
select convert(char(8),dateadd(s,datediff(s
    , DATEADD(s,-86399,GETDATE())
    , GETDATE()
),'1900-1-1'),8)
```

... after that it will return to zero:

```
select convert(char(8),dateadd(s,datediff(s
    , DATEADD(s,-86400,GETDATE())
    , GETDATE()
),'1900-1-1'),8)
```

Answer (score 4):

Because they are the same day (you don't have to worry about number of hours >24), you can just use a combination of DATEDIFF(second,time1,time2) and DATEADD(second,0,) to get a datetime value.

To format to hh:nn:ss, use `convert(char(8),answer,8)` but this is something better done by the reporting front end against the datetime result.

```
-- Late report
select *, dateadd(s,0,datediff(s,intime,actualintime)) late_by
from attendance
where intime < actualintime
```

Answer (score 1):

well, yes, you need to use DATEDIFF, and yes,  all that posted above works, but, if you  want to show 07:07:07 instead of 7:7:7, you have to do something like this:

```
Declare @starttime datetime, @endtime datetime, @seconds int, @minutes int, @hours int

Set @starttime ='2013-10-01 05:05:17'
Set @endtime = '2013-10-01 23:10:18'

set @hours = DateDiff(hour, @starttime, @endtime) 
set @minutes = DateDiff(minute, @starttime, @endtime);
set @seconds = DateDiff(second, @starttime, @endtime);

select case when DateDiff(minute, @starttime, @endtime) > 60 
        then CASE WHEN @hours >= 10 THEN cast(@hours as varchar(3))
                 ELSE '0' + cast(@hours as varchar(3)) END +':' + 
             CASE WHEN @minutes - (@hours * 60) >= 10 THEN
                 cast((@minutes - (@hours * 60)) as varchar(3))
                 ELSE '0' +cast((@minutes - (@hours * 60)) as varchar(3)) END
             + CASE WHEN (@seconds - (@minutes *60)) >= 10 THEN
                 +':' + cast(@seconds - (@minutes *60) as varchar(10)) 
                 ELSE ':0' + cast(@seconds - (@minutes *60) as varchar(10)) END
        ELSE '0' + cast(@minutes as varchar(3)) +':' + cast(@seconds as varchar(10)) 
end
```

It may not look very nice, but it gave me what i wanted.

Answer (score 1):

How about using CAST.

```
,CAST (Table1.DateTimeLatest-Table1.DateTimeFirst as time) as [Elapsed Time]
```

The raw result from SSMS from an apparatus table:
[SQL Return shows out to nanoseconds in this Data.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gc3GY.png)

For the report, as pasted in formatted Excel sheet:
[Formatted result column as hh:mm:ss.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53Awv.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, pickupdateandtime, GETDATE() AS CurrentTime, 
((DATEDIFF(day,GETDATE(),pickupdateandtime)) - 1) AS Days , 
convert(char(8),dateadd(s,datediff(s,GETDATE(),pickupdateandtime),'1900-1-
1'),8) AS 'Hours & Mins' FROM orders
```

Here's what worked for me. Thank you @lynx_74.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOmyJ.png

Answer (score 0):

Create a stored procedure to do the work and then just call the procedure passing your start and end dates.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetOperationDuration]  
   @DurationStart DATETIME, @DurationEnd DATETIME,
   @Duration VARCHAR(100) OUTPUT
AS  
BEGIN  
DECLARE @years INT, @months INT, @days INT,
   @hours INT, @minutes INT, @seconds INT, @milliseconds INT;

-- DOES NOT ACCOUNT FOR LEAP YEARS
SELECT @years = DATEDIFF(yy, @DurationStart, @DurationEnd)
IF DATEADD(yy, -@years, @DurationEnd) < @DurationStart 
SELECT @years = @years-1
SET @DurationEnd = DATEADD(yy, -@years, @DurationEnd)

SELECT @months = DATEDIFF(mm, @DurationStart, @DurationEnd)
IF DATEADD(mm, -@months, @DurationEnd) < @DurationStart 
SELECT @months=@months-1
SET @DurationEnd= DATEADD(mm, -@months, @DurationEnd)

SELECT @days=DATEDIFF(dd, @DurationStart, @DurationEnd)
IF DATEADD(dd, -@days, @DurationEnd) < @DurationStart 
SELECT @days=@days-1
SET @DurationEnd= DATEADD(dd, -@days, @DurationEnd)

SELECT @hours=DATEDIFF(hh, @DurationStart, @DurationEnd)
IF DATEADD(hh, -@hours, @DurationEnd) < @DurationStart 
SELECT @hours=@hours-1
SET @DurationEnd= DATEADD(hh, -@hours, @DurationEnd)

SELECT @minutes=DATEDIFF(mi, @DurationStart, @DurationEnd)
IF DATEADD(mi, -@minutes, @DurationEnd) < @DurationStart 
SELECT @minutes=@minutes-1
SET @DurationEnd= DATEADD(mi, -@minutes, @DurationEnd)

SELECT @seconds=DATEDIFF(s, @DurationStart, @DurationEnd)
IF DATEADD(s, -@seconds, @DurationEnd) < @DurationStart 
SELECT @seconds=@seconds-1
SET @DurationEnd= DATEADD(s, -@seconds, @DurationEnd)

SELECT @milliseconds=DATEDIFF(ms, @DurationStart, @DurationEnd)

SELECT @Duration= ISNULL(CAST(NULLIF(@years,0) AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' years,','')
     + ISNULL(' ' + CAST(NULLIF(@months,0) AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' months,','')    
     + ISNULL(' ' + CAST(NULLIF(@days,0) AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' days,','')
     + ISNULL(' ' + CAST(NULLIF(@hours,0) AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' hours,','')
     + ISNULL(' ' + CAST(@minutes AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' minutes and','')
     + ISNULL(' ' + CAST(@seconds AS VARCHAR(10)) 
     -- UNCOMMENT THEFOLLOWING IF YOU WANT MILLISECONDS INCLUDED
     --+ CASE
            --WHEN @milliseconds > 0
                --THEN '.' + CAST(@milliseconds AS VARCHAR(10)) 
            --ELSE ''
       --END 
     + ' seconds','')

SELECT @Duration
END
GO
```

Then just call using:
DECLARE @return_value int, @Duration varchar(100)

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[GetOperationDuration] @DurationStart, @DurationEnd, @Duration = @Duration OUTPUT

SELECT  @Duration as N'@Duration'

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd share my 2 cents. This fixes the overflow problems but only works with datetime not datetime2. It probably does not work with leap years or when clocks go backwards/forwards. I haven't tested with either.

```
declare @startTime datetime = getdate()
declare @endTime   datetime
select  [StartDate]      = @startTime,
        [EndDate]        = @endTime,
        [DD:HH:MM:SS.MS] = right( '00' + convert( varchar(20), datediff(hh, 0, @endTime - @startTime ) / 24 ), 2) + ':' + 
                           right( '00' + convert( varchar(20), datediff(hh, 0, @endTime - @startTime ) % 24 ), 2) + ':' + 
                           substring( convert( varchar(20), @endtime - @startTime, 114 ), 
                                      charindex( ':', convert( varchar(20), @endTime - @startTime, 114 ) ) + 1, 
                                      len( convert( varchar(20), @endTime - @startTime, 114 ) ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of these answers are so complex for no reason.
You can simply do like this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(TIME, END_TIME - START_TIME), 8) as 'ELAPSED_TIME (hh:mm:ss)' 
FROM your_table
```