# How to get a date result by subtracting one date from another

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

I would like to get the date difference in 00-00-00 00:00:00
when I subtract 2 dates, however the result I gets always starts with 1900-01-01.

How do I get this to only display the dates and time remaining.
or even value stating (X) days (X) hours (X) minutes

```
SELECT TOP 
   [Open_Date]
  ,[Close_Date]   
  ,([Open_Date]-[Close_Date]) as [test]
  ,[time_spent_sum]
  ,[support_lev]
  ,[Priority]
  ,[CountCases]
  ,[Last_Update_Status]
  ,[Last_Update_Date]
  ,[Customer Group]
  ,[Assignee Group]
  ,[3rd_Party]
  ,[rootcause]
  ,[location_name]
  ,[Dataline]
  ,[InterfaceID]
  ,[DAYS OPEN]
  FROM [mdb].[dbo].[ReportsView]
```

I have been messing around with some converts but not getting the desired effect.

```
case
  when [Close_Date] is null then format(convert(smalldatetime, dateadd(minute,  (datediff(minute,[Open_Date],getdate())), ''), 114),'d ''days''   HH ''Hrs'' :mm ''Mins'' ') 
  when [Close_Date] is not null then format(convert(smalldatetime, dateadd(minute,  (datediff(minute,[Open_Date],[Close_Date])), 0), 114),'d ''days''   HH ''Hrs'' :mm ''Mins'' ') 
  else null 
  end as [Total_call_open_time]
```

[DATES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtRn5.png)

Comment: See DATEDIFF function

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? They all support "DATE ARITHMETIC" but with different function names and syntax.

Comment: Hi I am using SQL server 2016

Comment: check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37614687/datediff-sql-server-2016-json

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550677/i-want-hours-min-second-difference-from-two-datetime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to more accurately represent the number of Days/hours/minutes/seconds between two time periods you need to find the actual time between the two dates, as `datediff` actually tells you how many boundaries you cross.

For example both of the following will return a value of 1 even though there is nearly 48 hours difference in the two periods:

```
select datediff(day,'2000-01-01 00:00:01','2000-01-02 23:59:59')
select datediff(day,'2000-01-01 23:59:59','2000-01-02 00:00:01')
```

As such, the following will do what you need it to, using div `/` and mod `%` to calculate total time spans and anything left over:

```
declare @d1 datetime = dateadd(day,-1,dateadd(hour,-2,dateadd(minute,-3,dateadd(second,-4,getdate()))))
declare @d2 datetime = getdate()

select datediff(hour,@d1,@d2)/24 as Days
        ,datediff(minute,@d1,@d2)/60%24 as Hours
        ,datediff(second,@d1,@d2)/60%60 as Minutes
        ,datediff(second,@d1,@d2)%60%60 as Seconds

        ,cast(datediff(hour,@d1,@d2)/24 as nvarchar(3)) + case when cast(datediff(day,@d1,@d2) as nvarchar(3)) = 1 then ' Day, ' else ' Days, ' end
         + cast(datediff(minute,@d1,@d2)/60%24 as nvarchar(3)) + case when cast(datediff(hour,@d1,@d2)%24 as nvarchar(3)) = 1 then ' Hour, ' else ' Hours, ' end
         + cast(datediff(second,@d1,@d2)/60%60 as nvarchar(3)) + case when cast(datediff(Minute,@d1,@d2)%60 as nvarchar(3)) = 1 then ' Minute, ' else ' Minutes, ' end
         + cast(datediff(Second,@d1,@d2)%60%60 as nvarchar(3)) + case when cast(datediff(Second,@d1,@d2)%60%60 as nvarchar(3)) = 1 then ' Second' else ' Seconds' end as TimeDifference
```

Comment: Thank you, this was perfect!